# If element's descendent has class x, add class to element's sibling that has a descendent with class y

Tags: jquery

I want to check to see if an element has a descendent with a certain class <del>X</del> Y. If so, I want to check that element's siblings to see if they have a descendent with a class <del>Y</del> Z. If so, I would like to add class to that sibling with the descendent with a class <del>Y</del> Z. (Edit: used the wrong class names in this paragraph; changed X to Y and Y to Z.)

HTML:

```
<div class="x">
    <div>
        <p class="y">Y</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="x">
    <div>
        <p class="z">Z</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('div').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('.y')){
      $(this).siblings('div').find('.z').closest('div').addClass(abc);    
    }
});
```

Here's a fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/7m02oyjq/

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please set up a correct fiddle.... http://jsfiddle.net/7m02oyjq/1/ use this one

Comment: totally unclear what you are looking for since you oversimplified the sample html. Please outline one element group that passes what you are looking for

Comment: At `html` at OP , does not appear that `.y` has any siblings ? Is expected result that _parent_ `.closest('div')` of `.z`  have `class` "abc" added ? Also  `"abc"` not appear to be surrounded by quotation marks ?

Comment: Sorry, yes, it was just the missing quotation marks around the 'abc.'

Answer (score 0):

Whaaaaaaaaat?  lol

```
var $firstDescendent = $(this).find('.classOne');

if ($firstDescendent.length > 0) {
    var $secondDescendent = $firstDescendent.find('.classTwo');

    if ($secondDescendent.length > 0) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Or you could probably chain that together

```
$(this).find('.classOne').find('.classTwo')[wash rinse repeat].dowhateveroperation();
```

Bah, or that could also be condensed

```
$(this).find('.classOne .classTwo .anotherClass .howeverDeepYouWantToGo').dowhateveroperation();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
$('div.outer > .x').not(':has(.y)').siblings(':has(.y)').addClass('someClass');
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m20fqvp5/)**</kbd>